# Finding median value per category

Tags: postgresql, median

I have a data table with columns "field" and "conc" (which is short for concentration). I am trying to output the each type of field (the categories are cosmos, egs etc) along with the associated median value of the conc statistic for each field type.

This is what I have tried:

SELECT field, percentile_cont(0.5)::numeric FROM galaxies GROUP BY conc LIMIT 5;

ERROR:  function percentile_cont(numeric) does not exist

LINE 1: SELECT field, percentile_cont(0.5)::numeric FROM galaxies GR...

However, I am getting this error and am not exactly sure how to go about extracting the field name with the median value for conc for each field type

Answer (score 1):

As indicated in [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-aggregate.html) for PostgreSQL, `WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY...)` is mandatory for the ordered-set aggregate functions like `percentile_cont`.

If you want the median of the conc, then grouping by conc is surely the wrong thing to do.  So you might want something like this:

```
SELECT field, percentile_cont(0.5) within group (order by conc)::numeric 
    FROM galaxies GROUP BY field LIMIT 5;
```